# How to add static text between the groups?

Tags: jasper-reports

I wonder how I can achieve the following structure:

Loop of tables:

1. Table 1
2. Table 2
3. Table 3

This is just a introduction text about Chairs

Loop of Chairs:

1. Chair 1
2. Chair 2

Introduction text about our company

Loop of members:

1. Member 1
2. Member 2

How can I achieve above setup?

I just want to add some text between the groups, and that the loop of items in a group is independent. I am not able to put two groups after each other , only group in group.

Hopefully above is clearly.

---

At this moment I get the following result:

> Text: About tables
>
> **Table 1**
>
> ---- Text: This is just a introduction text about Chairs
>
> ---- Chair 1
>
> ---- Text: Introduction text about our company
>
> ---- Member 1
>
> **Table 2**
>
> ---- Text: This is just a introduction text about Chairs
>
> ---- Chair 2
>
> ---- Text: Introduction text about our company
>
> ---- Member 2

I don't want the group nested in the first group.

Note: both groups have the same expression because the information is stored in the same table: $F[info_id]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with just using the group Footer:
[image]

This is my jrxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.2.1  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Stackoverflow" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="0bf40f57-106b-468c-aad0-0542f71e2399">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
(start_date + (LEVEL - 1)) AS start_date,
to_char(start_date + (LEVEL - 1), 'iw') week
FROM (
SELECT 
sysdate  AS start_date,
sysdate +20 AS end_date
FROM dual)
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 + (end_date - start_date)]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="START_DATE" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="WEEK" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <group name="WEEK">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{WEEK}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="30">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="3eb19eee-5434-4351-9788-b48fb2cc6fef"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{WEEK}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="30">
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="5c713058-5d7c-4992-a20c-d35906bb9c15"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="14" isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Static Text]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="30">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="278" height="30" uuid="eb6c2cf4-2e94-4886-a251-927230710920">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{START_DATE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="278" y="0" width="277" height="30" uuid="7b30b722-c582-4b8d-8336-932bf0cf3c06"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{WEEK}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Maybe clarify your question a little bit?

Comment: Thanks Markus. Your JRXML is clearly but I don't understand it yet. I have edited my first post with the new structure, hopefully it's more clearly now.
Thanks again, much appreciated.